# Change values in an array using foreach

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file I import, and I need to change the format of a column (backed_up_ts) to remove the original data in the column and replace it with the updated format.

The original data for each row in the column looks like this:

```
Tue Sep 13 07:46:26 MDT 2016
```

The first part of my code formats every row so that it can be compared to a date:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewReport.csv" | Select display_client_name, backed_up_ts
$csv = foreach ($budate in $csv.backed_up_ts) {
$budate = $budate.Substring(3)
$budate = $budate.Replace("MDT", "")
$budate = $budate.Replace("MST", "")
$budate = $budate.Split(" ")
$budate = $budate[1] + " " + $budate[2] + " " + $budate[5]
$budate = ($budate | Get-Date -Format d)
```

From here I need to take the updated format (in the `$budate` value) and replace the original data in the `$csv.backed_up_ts` array.

However, the value of `$budate` is only the last value of the object in the foreach loop (3/30/16).
The value of `$csv.backed_up_ts` remains in the array in its original format (Wednesday, August 30th, EST, 2016).

I need the original array `$csv.backed_up_ts` to be replaced by the coordinating values created by the `$budate`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer based on clarification of desired transformation of data.

*Code*

```
# demonstrate changing columnn data in csv input
$input = @"
header1, header2
value11, "Tue Sep 13 07:46:26 MDT 2016"
value21, "Tue Oct 19 07:46:26 MDT 2017"
"@

$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv $input

"original"
$csv

foreach ($item in $csv)
{
    # modify the header2 column in our csv input
    $parts = $item.header2.Split(' ')
    $newDate = $parts[1] + " " + $parts[2] + " " + $parts[5]
    $item.header2 = [DateTime]::Parse($newDate) | Get-Date -Format d
}

"new"
$csv
```

*Output*

```
original
header1 header2                     
------- -------                     
value11 Tue Sep 13 07:46:26 MDT 2016
value21 Tue Oct 19 07:46:26 MDT 2017
new
value11 9/13/2016                   
value21 10/19/2017
```

Comment: So - in trying it with your format, it's not accepting it. let me explain further.

The original data in header 2 is "Wed Mar 30 10:03:45 MDT 2016"

So in the foreach part - i need to get rid of a lot the data, before i can convert it to a date.    

   `foreach ($item in $csv.header2) {$item = $item.replace("MDT", "")`
This gets the data into a format that can be converted to a date. 
When i convert it to a date, i then try your code `$item.header2 = $item.header2 -replace *, $item`

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question or add a comment with what you are trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is a better way.  For a value in the format "Wed Mar 30 10:03:45 MDT 2016", what exactly do you want it changed to?

Comment: So your code would work - if the -replace parameter would accept a wildcard * - so it would remove everything in that object, and replace it entirely. Also, it can't be replaced by a static '2' - it is replaced by a dynamic variable.

Comment: Updated my question. Hopefully it's more understandable.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Hope this is helpful.